# how to execute an aspx page (JavaScript function on page load) without loading page in browser

Tags: javascript, asp.net, api

We are generating a google chart on an aspx page and sending calling and API with the path of the chart.

The page is running fine when we are loading in the browser.

But we need to call page URL using API and execute without loading on the browser.

We are calling javascript function on page load, but that is not executing. If we call a c# function that we can call. code for generating charts is placed in a javascript function,

So, how we call that?

Please suggest.

Code that we are calling on page load:

```
this.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "test", "SendMessage('" + Session["msg"].ToString() + "')", true);
```

`SendMessage` defined in `aspx` page.

Comment: Please share the sample code.

Comment: We are calling a function javascript function "SendMessage" from cs page. 

this.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "test", "SendMessage('" + Session["msg"].ToString() + "')", true);

Comment: You want to execute a method using API call that will return json data to you, right?

Comment: Yes Right, on that json data I am generating graph which i need to return in API.

Comment: If you want to call a `c#` code, then you should see how to write a `[WebMethod]` in aspx page.

Comment: That we have written. But generating graph code is in JavaScript only, How do we execute that code without loading page in browser.

Comment: You cannot do that.

Comment: JavaScript runs in the browser, you cannot run it outside of the browser unless you are using `NodeJS`

Comment: I think you can [employ this approach](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/bind-gridview-using-jquery-load-in-asp-net-with-no-page-reload/) when loading things from different pages of your site.